# How to build square cells in a SwiftUI LazyVGrid containing dynamic type

Tags: swiftui, lazyvgrid, dynamic-type-feature

I'm trying to build a `LazyVGrid`, that contains square cells that dynamically size with the text inside them, something like this:

```
struct BandView: View {
    
    let bands: [Band]
    
    var body: some View {
        LazyVGrid(columns: [GridItem(.adaptive(minimum: 120))]) {
            ForEach(bands, id: \.self) { band in
                BandCell(band: band)
            }
        }
        .frame(maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
        .padding()
    }
}

struct BandCell: View {
    
    let band: Band
    
    var body: some View {
        GroupBox {
            VStack(alignment: .leading, spacing: 8) {
                Text(band.leadSinger)
                    .lineLimit(1)
                Text("\(band.songs) songs")
            }
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity, alignment: .topLeading)
        } label: {
                Text(band.name)
                    .lineLimit(2)
        }
        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fill)
    }
}

struct BandView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    
    static var bands = [
        Band(name: "Wet Leg", leadSinger: "Rhian Teasdale", songs: 2),
        Band(name: "The Cure", leadSinger: "Robert Smith", songs: 6),
        Band(name: "Dave Dee, Dozy, Beaky, Mick & Tich ", leadSinger: "Dave Dee", songs: 5)
    ]
    
    static var previews: some View {
        BandView(bands: bands)
    }
}


struct Band: Hashable {
    let name: String
    let leadSinger: String
    let songs: Int
}
```

which gives me the following when using a **large** dynamic type size:

[image]

However, when I increase the font size to **accessibility 3** or more the cells take up more space so that they overlap the frame of the grid (and each other):

[image]

I was expecting the cells to grow, but as I'm using `GridItem(.adaptive)` I assumed they would move onto separate rows.

Changing the aspect ratio to `fit` rather than `fill`, i.e.

```
.aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
```

and the cells stretch vertically, so don't keep the aspect ratio.

[image]

What am I missing?

Comment: I think its because LazyVStack is defining the nr of columns upfront and proposing their sizes to the child views, which then adapt to it.  It seems like in LazyVStack the child view is not able to report back that it needs more space (which is usually possible in SwiftUI layout hierarchy). I suppose the only workaround is to skip LazyVStack altogether.

Comment: Have you found out a solution to share or is your initial problem still a topical issue, please? 